# File upload change filename in java

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets, frameworks

File upload change filename in java serclet.How to rename a file (change file name) in java servlet.Rename and save the database.please help me.

my file upload code.

```
public class AjaxImage extends MNServlet {
    private static URLCodec urlcodec = new URLCodec("UTF-8");
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
         String id = request.getParameter(Plugin.PLUGIN_ID_VARIABLE);

        if (isMultipart) {          
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            try {
                List<FileItem> multiparts = upload.parseRequest(request);
                for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        String road = "";
                        try {                           
                            String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                            String relativeWebPath = "/image";
                            String absoluteFilePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
                            item.write(new File(absoluteFilePath, FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName())));
                            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                            String data = "";
                            try {
                                data =urlcodec.decode(request.getParameter("data"), "UTF-8");
                            } catch (DecoderException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {}
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line

```
   item.write(new File(absoluteFilePath, FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName())));
```

Simply switch `item.getName()` to be the name you would like the file to have once saved.